# How to recover SVN Revision History after a "Replace" action on a File

Tags: svn, replace, repository, action, history

**I have completed a "replacing" action on a single file and committed it. See the TortoiseSVN "Show Log" window below.**

[image: TortoiseSVN "Show Log" Window]

**It now has no revision history.**

Forgive my novice level and unfamiliarity with SVN and TortoiseSVN, but I am in need of layman's instructions for restoring the revision history of a single file after I performed and committed the "replacement" action on it.

I have tried to checkout an older revision of that file, but the revision history is not recovered.

Thank you in advance for your instruction.

Comment: Try to run `svn log` at the root of repository to get all! Then grep your commit message to see if there is trace of what you are searching for!

Answer (score 1):

I think this maybe still an open issue.

check this link:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=276018