# How to recover SVN history of a file which is replaced with another one?

Tags: php, svn, phpstorm, history

I have searched for this issue and find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54140204/how-to-recover-svn-revision-history-after-a-replace-action-on-a-file) but I can't find any proper solution.
I am working on a project which is under SVN using PhpStorm.
I replaced a file with another one as follows:

- make a copy of the file: file.php,              file1.php;
- renamed files:           file.php -> file0.php, file1.php -> file.php;
- commit file.php (the new file);

Now I can not see the history before this file replacement.

What is the way to recover the file history in the SVN or revert to the previous state?

Comment: If your file.php was already under revision control then this commit should be register as a modifiction. Did you use SVN rename to rename the file.php -> file0.php?

Comment: I did not do what you mention. I replace the new version manually and out of SVN options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one possible solution to the issue:

If the project is running in a group, then we need to find someone in the group who has not updated the lost file, therefore, has an un-updated version of the lost file.

This un-updated file contains all the history of the main file which we have lost its SVN history.

So, we can commit this un-updated file with new codes and all the history will be in the SVN again.

Answer (score 0):

I've just executed all the steps you've mentioned and I see all the history when I run `svn log file.php` or `svn log file0.php`. The problem is that you most likely did not use the SVN commands or you removed or replaced the files without using the SVN client.

Use the correct `svn copy` and `svn rename` commands and you will see all the history before your copy or rename operations.

Comment: Thanks for your mention. But, unfortunately, I did not use the way you have mentioned for file replacement. I just renamed the file and replaced the new one with the old one, out of SVN options. Nevertheless, is there any way to revert changes and recover history of the file?

Comment: @MajidRafei See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo

Comment: Is there any way to recover the history of a file which is replaced with another one without considering `svn copy` and `svn rename` commands?